# Full List of Countries participating in the UN COP 21 in Paris

Tags: united-nations, paris-agreement

Does anyone have a full list of countries who took part in the UN Climate Change Conference?

I know that it where about 150. Would find it interesting who exactly where involved. On top about 200 Countries signed the agreement. I am also curious to know which countries did this and which did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Provisional list of participants](http://unfccc.int/resource/docs/2015/cop21/eng/inf03p01.pdf) (PDF):

[image: COP21 participants]

- **196 signatories** of [UNFCCC (United Nations Framework Convention on Climate Change)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Framework_Convention_on_Climate_Change) are listed [here](http://unfccc.int/essential_background/convention/status_of_ratification/items/2631.php);
- 2 Observer States are The Holy See and Palestine ([proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Framework_Convention_on_Climate_Change#Parties));
- I could not find the full list of Observer Organizations and Media;

Further information:

- [Detailed list of participants](http://unfccc.int/documentation/documents/items/3595.php?id=3595&searchterm=list+of+participants) — three PDF documents dated 11 Dec 2015;
- [Some analytics](http://www.carbonbrief.org/analysis-which-countries-have-sent-the-most-delegates-to-cop21) about sizes of delegations, including stats on **Negotiating blocs**;